# Поиск подстроки в нескольких строках

Tags: алгоритм, строки, поиск, подстрока, нечеткий-поиск

Есть задача работы с бегущими строками (из новостей, например).
Необходимо отделить (если есть) часть текста, которая не двигается, пример:

BBC NEWS| Дональд Трамп сказал что-то ст

BBC NEWS| альд Трамп сказал что-то страш

BBC NEWS| д Трамп сказал что-то страшное

Собственно, хочется выделить "BBC NEWS|" и удалить. Проблема в том, что заранее неизвестно, есть такие заставки или нет, в начале, в середине или конце. Знаем только, что если она есть, то она не меняется и всегда в одной области экрана.

Попытался формализовать:

Pi = [Ai, Bi, Ci], i in 0..N, - строка.

Необходимо найти B такую, что

Ai != A{i+1}, Bi == B{i+1}, Ci != C{i+1} для 2*N/3 <= K <= N строк

Position(Bi) = const для i in 0..N

Ai, Ci могут быть пустыми.

Может кто знает, есть ли решения подобного или хотя бы где искать? Пока в голову приходит только перебор, но поскольку B может не быть, то придется перебирать ещё и подстроки с разными длинами - не самое лучшее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться re.sub, который позволяет искать в строке и удалять или изменять нужные подстроки.

```
import re

running_string_with_channel_name = "BBC NEWS| Дональд Трамп BBC NEWS| сказал что-то BBC NEWS| страшное BBC NEWS|"

without_channel_name = re.sub(r'BBC NEWS.{1,2}', " ", running_string_with_channel_name).replace("  ", " ")

for i, ch in enumerate(without_channel_name):
   print(without_channel_name[i:])
```

**Вывод:**

```
 Дональд Трамп сказал что-то страшное 
 ональд Трамп сказал что-то страшное 
 нальд Трамп сказал что-то страшное 
 альд Трамп сказал что-то страшное
```

Comment: Так вопрос не в том, как вырезать.
Нужно
1. определить, присутствует ли некий неизменяемый текст в строке
2. если да, то найти его string txt = search_static_text_block(...)
3. и только 3й шаг - то, что вы написали - вырезать.

Comment: @PavelFedorov,  ведь так всё и происходит, re.sub по заданной маске находит необходимые элементы, если они есть и убирает (можно изменить, если нужно), а если вы на вход подадите строку без названия канала, то строка останется неизменной... или если нет названия канала нужно чтоб возвращалось какое-то значение, так?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь делается предположение, что в этих строках есть только одна область, в которой происходит совпадение символов.

```
s1 = 'BBC NEWS| Дональд Трамп сказал что-то ст'

s2 = 'BBC NEWS| альд Трамп сказал что-то страш'

s3 = 'BBC NEWS| д Трамп сказал что-то страшное'

size = len(s1)

diff = [s1[i] == s2[i] == s3[i] for i in range(size)]

try:
    start = diff.index(True)
    end = size - diff[-1::-1].index(True) - 1
    print(s1[:start] + s1[end + 1:])
    print(s2[:start] + s2[end + 1:])
    print(s3[:start] + s3[end + 1:])
except ValueError:
    print('Нет такой области')
```